# How to use CheckBox for set string in Android

Tags: java, android, checkbox, android-checkbox

In my application i want use **3** `CheckBox` and i want when check of each this `CheckBoxs` add one world into my `String`.
**For example :** I want **3** `CheckBox` (**chBoxFree**, **chBoxDownload**, **chBoxBuy**) and when check each of this `CheckBoxs` add **Free**, **Download**, **Buy** into one `String` and when *uncheck* `CheckBox` **remove** from this `String`.
If checked the **chBoxFree**, **chBoxBuy** add **"free-buy"** in this `string` value and when **uncheck** **chBoxBuy**, **remove** **buy** from this string

How can i it?

Comment: instead of trying to add/remove words from a string it would be much easier to rebuild it by iterating over checkboxes whenever their checked state changes

Comment: @Pawel, can you send to send to me code? really need your help. thanks

Comment: @DJAl, Check answer for your clarification. And it's not a good practice to ask question to get answer without doing any coding or research. You have to post your own effort and then ask for the help. Hope you understand. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can observe the `checked/unchecked` inside `onCheckedChanged` and do your operation accordingly.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {
    private TextView textView;
    private List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textView = findViewById(R.id.textview1);

        CheckBox checkBox1 = findViewById(R.id.checkbox1);
        CheckBox checkBox2 = findViewById(R.id.checkbox2);
        CheckBox checkBox3 = findViewById(R.id.checkbox3);

        checkBox1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        checkBox2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        checkBox3.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if(isChecked) {
            switch (buttonView.getId()) {
                case R.id.checkbox1:
                    list.add("Free");
                    break;
                case R.id.checkbox2:
                    list.add("Download");
                    break;
                case R.id.checkbox3:
                    list.add("Buy");
            }
        } else {
            switch (buttonView.getId()) {
                case R.id.checkbox1:
                    list.remove("Free");
                    break;
                case R.id.checkbox2:
                    list.remove("Download");
                    break;
                case R.id.checkbox3:
                    list.remove("Buy");
            }
        }

        textView.setText(TextUtils.join("-", list));
    }
}
```